# Closing JDialog box from a thread

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jdialog, event-dispatching

I have a JDialg for showing the progress of a certain task. To display and hide the dialog box I have following methods,

```
public class ProgressDisplayer extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    ......
    public void s_show() {
            this.setTitle("Month End Status");
            setModal(true);
            setResizable(false);
            pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void s_hide() {
            this.dispose();
        }

    ...........
}
```

When I try to close this JDialog box from a Thread as below, although it is displayed properly yet I cannot hide it when I call `pd.s_hide()` method.

```
...........
public void run() {            
                ProgressDisplayer pd = new ProgressDisplayer();
                pd.s_show();                    
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                pd.s_hide();
}
.............
```

please assist me.

Comment: *"When .. from a Thread .. is not hide."*  Have you confirmed that it hides correctly when **not** called from the thread?  Seems like a `setVisible(false);` would not go astray.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this doesn't work as you expect is that for modal dialogs, the method `setVisible()` will block the calling thread until the dialog is closed.  This means the calling thread will block on `pd.s_show()`, and will not continue to the next line (`Thread.sleep(1000)`) until the user closes the dialog.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove the call to `setModal(true)`.  However, you'll lose the modal behavior.

P.S.  As radai mentions, it is not thread-safe to call into Swing code from a thread other than the event dispatch thread.  Your code is also broken in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

swing operations should always be called from the swing event dispatcher thread only.
try using SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() to perform your gui work from non-gui threads.
you can see some examples here: http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html